# Getting a return value from a button's action method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, ibaction

I have a button, and I've set an action in code:

```
[buttonOk addTarget:self action:@selector(check:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The `check:` method returns an `int`. How can I receive this `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a different method that calls `check:`. Have this method process the return value.

```
- (void)mymethod:(id)sender {
  int value = [self check:sender];
  // use your value or send it somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Function *check* returns int, how can I receive this int?

[An action method should have `IBAction` as its return type](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html), and `IBAction` is defined as `void`. You can call whatever method you want from inside the action method, but the action itself should not return anything.